# Can i import my Diablo 3 demo character into the full console version?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

The demo appears to have a save and make progress. Can this save be imported into the full version? What about vice versa (can I play a save from the full version within the demo)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you play a character in the demo and buy the full game, this will be transferred across.

[Blizzard FAQ on the matter.](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-console-demo-faq)

Comment: I just booted up the full game version on the 360 and nothing happens with my demo data, there is no import message or anything. The characters are not on my main character selection screen as well. There is also no option to "force" import from a menu. There is also no way to ask Blizzard through their help system since they always redirect you to Microsoft or Sony. Also my stash in-game has none of my items from the demo as well. Trying to get a hold of blizzard. About this since I hate calling Microsoft.